# Is it possible to constraint an object on a vertice?

Tags: constraints

Is it possible to contraint an object on a vertice instead of the entire object? Like an arrow on a body. Or to a face, so that the constraint object would move according to the face's normal?

Comment: There are a few options.  You can vertex parent, or you can designate the vertex with a vertex group and use a copy location constraint.  Vertex parenting or copy transforms can be used with a triangle instead of a single vert to acquire positiion + rotation.  If you need to acquire scale, you need additional markers set up so that you can use stretch-to constraints to generate basis vector scale.  Bones are the easiest way to set these markers up.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going on memory here but basically you do the parent procedure, select the child, and with shift held select the parent.  Press Tab and you'll be in edit mode for the parent model.  Select a vertice and choose that option in the pop-up.  Press Tab again to return to object mode.  If the vertice is at the model's origin point, when the object rotates, the child shouldn't because the vertice won't be moving in any axis.  It's an ideal way to attach a camera to models.